# How to make Vim "repeat search" direction absolute instead of relative?

Tags: vim, vimrc, vi

I am looking for a way to make Vim always go backwards whether I press repeat last `,` or `N` and forward when using their pairs `;` or `n`.
Currently Vim is using a relative direction which depends on the move my previous search was using.

I prefer not using any plugin at the moment, any `.vimrc` or commands would be OK for me.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look here: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2365/71

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt thank you that's exactly what I was looking for! I am also answering my question with ```,``` and ```;``` to complete this post.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution to add into your `.vimrc`
Based on this solution https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2366

```
nnoremap <expr> n (v:searchforward ? 'n' : 'N')
nnoremap <expr> N (v:searchforward ? 'N' : 'n')

nnoremap <expr> ; (getcharsearch().forward ? ';' : ',')
nnoremap <expr> , (getcharsearch().forward ? ',' : ';')
```